# Steam Web API: Am I allowed to use it as private person?

Tags: steam

I had the following idea:

> Creating a non commercial webpage, which looks through all steam comments to see games has the most playtime. Imagine a ranking like "average playtime" #1: SimCity 66.3h, #2 Monkey Island 59.4h etc.

I've seen there is an web API given by steam which seems to fulfill my needs:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview

I'm curious if:

- Am I as private person allowed to use it?
- Do I need dev key?
- Is there a GET request to get all AppIDs of all games?

Comment: Sites that already do this: [Steam Ladder](https://steamladder.com/games/), [Astats](https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Games.php?Sort=8), [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1179973/steam-games-peak-concurrent-players/)

Comment: I moved the sites you found into a comment, since it didn't really make sense for them to be in your question.

Comment: Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of sites, that implement things like you seem to have searched for.
Most famous one is probably https://steamdb.info/.

Regarding your other questions:

> Am I as private person allowed to use it?

You are as long as you follow the [Terms of usage](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apiterms?).

> Do I need dev key?

Many requests are public and do not require any kind of key. Here an example call in Postman ([http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v2/?appid=440&count=3\r\n](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v2/?appid=440&count=3%5Cr%5Cn)):

[image: Postman]

Delivers:

```
{
"appnews": {
    "appid": 440,
    "newsitems": [
        {
            "gid": "4347669995461247616",
            "title": "Operation Peculiar Pandemonium",
            "url": "https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/news/externalpost/steam_community_announcements/4347669995461247616",
            "is_external_url": true,
            "author": "erics",
            "contents": "[img]{STEAM_CLAN_IMAGE}/554111/5218399b6f17a222a394c2965511454855b98d2c.png[/img]\n(Image credit: Mayor Rev)\n\nRed alert, mercs! April is drawing near, and an unusual yet familiar virus has fallen upon the robotic hordes once again. The aptly named \"Meme Machines\" are back to wreak havoc, blunder about, and provide a healthy helping of the best medicine money can't buy—laughter! Now sign up for the cheapest insurance plan you can find and grab your guns, because it's time for a comedy session!\n\n[url=https://mvm.pineapple.tf/servers]Operation Peculiar Pandemonium[/url] is an April Fools Mann vs Machine tour brought to you by [url=https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791470918359]Moonlight MvM[/url] that once again pits the Mercs against a meme-fueled robotic onslaught. Complete all the waves in this intermediate-difficulty tour to earn a special [b]pink tank medal[/b]! Event servers are available in North America, South America, Europe, Asia, and Australia.\n\nIn addition to wrecking the meme machines, you can also donate to the charity fundraiser for [b]The National Breast Cancer Foundation of Australia[/b]. Up to [b]three[/b] pink donor medals are up for grabs for donations of [b]A$6[/b] (US$5), [b]A$20[/b] (US$15), and [b]A$33[/b] (US$25). Both cash and TF2 items are accepted. [url=https://mvm.pineapple.tf/charity]Click here for more information on how to donate[/url].\n\nHave fun, but don’t delay or else the meme machines will conquer the world by [b]April 11th[/b]!\n\nImportant Links:\n[list]\n[*][url=https://mvm.pineapple.tf/servers]Servers List[/url]\n[*][url=https://mvm.pineapple.tf/charity]Charity Info[/url]\n[*][url=https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791470918359]Steam Group[/url]\n[*][url=https://moonlight.tf/discord]Discord[/url]\n[/list]\n",
            "feedlabel": "Community Announcements",
            "date": 1648755657,
            "feedname": "steam_community_announcements",
            "feed_type": 1,
            "appid": 440
        },
        {
            "gid": "4347669995461255135",
            "title": "Operation Peculiar Pandemonium",
            "url": "https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/news/externalpost/tf2_blog/4347669995461255135",
            "is_external_url": true,
            "author": "",
            "contents": "<a href=\"https://mvm.pineapple.tf/charity\"><img src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/news/136492/pandemonium_small.png?t=1496190900\"></a>\n(Image credit: <a href=\"https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198045651005\">Mayor Rev</a>)<br><br>\n\n<p>Red alert, mercs! April is drawing near, and an unusual yet familiar virus has fallen upon the robotic hordes once again. The aptly named \"Meme Machines\" are back to wreak havoc, blunder about, and provide a healthy helping of the best medicine money can't buy—laughter! Now sign up for the cheapest insurance plan you can find and grab your guns, because it's time for a comedy session!</p><br>\n\n<p><a href=\"https://mvm.pineapple.tf/servers\">Operation Peculiar Pandemonium</a> is an April Fools Mann vs Machine tour brought to you by <a href=\"https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791470918359\">Moonlight MvM</a> that once again pits the Mercs against a meme-fueled robotic onslaught. Complete all the waves in this intermediate-difficulty tour to earn a special <b>pink tank medal</b>! Event servers are available in North America, South America, Europe, Asia, and Australia.</p><br>\n\n<p>In addition to wrecking the meme machines, you can also donate to the charity fundraiser for <b>The National Breast Cancer Foundation of Australia</b>. Up to <b>three</b> pink donor medals are up for grabs for donations of <b>A$6</b> (US$5), <b>A$20</b> (US$15), and <b>A$33</b> (US$25). Both cash and TF2 items are accepted. <a href=\"https://mvm.pineapple.tf/charity\">Click here for more information on how to donate</a>.</p><br>\n\n<p>Have fun, but don’t delay or else the meme machines will conquer the world by <b>April 11th</b>!</p><br>\n\n<p>Important Links:<ul>\n<li><a href=\"https://mvm.pineapple.tf/servers\">Servers List</a>\n<li><a href=\"https://mvm.pineapple.tf/charity\">Charity Info</a>\n<li><a href=\"https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791470918359\">Steam Group</a>\n<li><a href=\"https://moonlight.tf/discord\">Discord</a></ul>\n</p><br>",
            "feedlabel": "TF2 Blog",
            "date": 1648755540,
            "feedname": "tf2_blog",
            "feed_type": 0,
            "appid": 440
        },
        {
            "gid": "4347669995457917247",
            "title": "Team Fortress 2 Update Released",
            "url": "https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/news/externalpost/steam_community_announcements/4347669995457917247",
            "is_external_url": true,
            "author": "erics",
            "contents": "An update to Team Fortress 2 has been released. The update will be applied automatically when you restart Team Fortress 2. The major changes include:\n\n[list]\n[*]Updated Taunt: Shooter's Stakeout to fix LOD bugs\n[*]Updated class portraits with nomip/nolod flags\n[/list]\n",
            "feedlabel": "Community Announcements",
            "date": 1648676657,
            "feedname": "steam_community_announcements",
            "feed_type": 1,
            "appid": 440,
            "tags": [
                "patchnotes"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 3176
}
}
```

> Is there a GET request to get all AppIDs of all games?

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=STEAMKEY&format=json

This answer can also be found on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330864/steam-api-all-games

Comment: Sir, your answer is on point. Thanks a lot!